# How to use the Element API plugin only when logged in?

Tags: plugin-elementapi, authentication

I want to use the Element API plugin, but the content must only be visible when users are logged in. How I do this for a section? Is it possible to use `requirelogin` or `currentUser` for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the people who needs something similar. The basic auth function for the Element API.

```
function requireLogin()
{
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");

    if (craft()->userSession->isLoggedIn()) {
        // you are authenticated
    } else {
        // check params
        $loginName = craft()->request->getQuery('loginName');
        $password = craft()->request->getQuery('password');

        if (craft()->userSession->login($loginName, $password)) {
            // login success
            $user = craft()->userSession->getUser();
        } else {
            // login fails echo message
            $errorCode = craft()->userSession->getLoginErrorCode();
            $errorMessage = craft()->userSession->getLoginErrorMessage($errorCode, $loginName);
            craft()->end(JsonHelper::encode(array('data' => array( ['status' => 'error','message' =>'wrong login']  ))));
        }
    }

}
```

And you use these params in your url: `?loginName=username&password=yourpass`

Comment: FTR, I'd highly recommend _not_ passing username/passwords combinations in the querystring as it opens up all sorts of security related issues. You can use some alternative authentication methods, such as token based.

Comment: I am switched over to the JWT manager

Answer (score 5):

If you want to restrict the whole API, you can add some code to the top of your `/config/elementapi.php` file (right below `namespace Craft;`) that checks for a logged in user, and ends the request with an appropriate status if the user isn't logged in:

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

$user = craft()->userSession->getUser();
if (!$user) {
    HeaderHelper::setHeader(array('status' => 404));
    craft()->end();
}
```

Note that you can replace the `404` with [another HTTP status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error) if you want to; pick whatever feels appropriate to your app.

*If you want to restrict specific endpoints*, but leave others open, the best approach is probably to wrap the above code in a function, i.e.

```
<?php 
namespace Craft;

function requireLogin() {
    $user = craft()->userSession->getUser();
    if (!$user) {
        HeaderHelper::setHeader(array('status' => 404));
        craft()->end();
    }
}

return [
    ...
```

Then, it's simply a matter of calling this function from your restricted endpoints' `transformer` callbacks:

```
'news.json' => [
    'elementType' => 'Entry',
    'criteria' => ['section' => 'news'],
    'transformer' => function(EntryModel $entry) {

        // This endpoint should be restricted
        requireLogin();

        return [
            'title' => $entry->title,
            ...
        ];

    },
],
...
```

Comment: Thanx @Mats tried it today and works like a charm, I also added basic authentication for usage in an app

Comment: Is it possible to add an array in the craft()->end(); tag? On fail login I want to return a json object wit 'status' => 'error' or something like that

Comment: @MaartenHeideman Yes, that's possible – something like this would work fine: `craft()->end(JsonHelper::encode(['status' => 'error']));`

Comment: You should probably not use HTTP status 404 if you're returning an error object though.